# How can I forward my http/https request to 2 different upstream proxies based in the destilanation url?

Tags: iptables, nginx, proxy, squid, forwarding

Hi I am quite struggling to find a good solution to my problem. I have to forward http/https requests from my (Linux) server to 2 different proxy based on the destination URL.

I've tried different solutions based on iptables (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and nginx (8,9,10,11,12) as a forward proxy but I cannot make one working.
With Squid I am able to achieve it but I was looking to a more lightweight solution.

I do not necessarily want to have a transparent proxy setup though it would be good. So setting up the http_proxy and https_proxy on my Linux server it is feasible.

My 2 different upstream proxies (Squid flavor) are not managed by me and therefore I cannot change their config.

At the desktop level, the proxy.pac config can be used, but this approach is not feasible on a Linux server where multiple tools need to run and get the upstream proxy dynamically.

Let me add a diagram to make it clear:
[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.There is a http server some proxies and some URLs, that much is clear. However, I can not figure out how they are related, or what you want to do with them.

Comment: Added a diagram to clarify it.